# Could it in theory be possible to produce AM and FM gravitational waves?

Tags: gravitational-waves

I'm borrowing the concept of a radio and having fun with space-time, my argument is that since gravitational wave have amplitude and frequency it is very much similar to electromagnetic wave such as radio wave. I can imagine why any DJ would quickly abandon this idea as for me I can't afford LIGO, anyway if it is possible what kind of noise can interfere with a AM gravitational wave signal beside itself?

Comment: You should note that the notion of controlling one of those properties and varying only the other is a very artificial one and it mostly only appears in engineered devices. Indeed the signal that LIGO reported on recently modulates in both properties simultaneously (as expected from the models, natch).

Answer (score 0):

Creating detectable gravitational waves would be extremely challenging. If that can be achieved, then, modulation (AM, or FM) would not be that hard. The first part itself, is not practical.